# Segmentation fault error while trying to get file extension in C

Tags: c, fedora

I'm trying to write a function in C, taking in entry a file, that returns 1 if the file extension is png, jpg, etc.

This is what I wrote :

```
int estImage(struct dirent *fichier)
{
    char nomFichier[256];
    strncpy (nomFichier, fichier->d_name, 255);

    char *dot = strrchr(nomFichier, '.');

    char * listeExtensionImage[] = {".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp" };
    int len = sizeof(listeExtensionImage)/sizeof(listeExtensionImage[0]);

    printf(dot); //Just to test

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(listeExtensionImage[i], dot))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

If I put in entry a file that's not a picture (a .c file for example), then it will return 0 with no problem, and the printf(dot) will display ".c".

But, if I try to entry a picture file (.jpg or any other that I listed), I have the message **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**.
Then, I realised that the problem comes from the line :

```
if(!strcmp(listeExtensionImage[i], dot))
```

If I delete the for instruction, and everything in-between, then I don't have the error anymore.

But I don't understand why I have this problem, because I have a similary test in the same program, and it works :

```
int estExecutable(struct dirent *fichier) 
{
   char nomFichier[256]; // Variable qui contiendra le nom du fichier
   strncpy (nomFichier, fichier->d_name, 255); 
   const char *dot = strrchr(nomFichier, '.'); 
   if(strcmp(dot,".exe")==0)
   {
       printf(nomFichier);
       return 1;
   }
   else
       return 0;
}
```

This function does work, and I don't see what's the difference between my two functions. Can someone help me please? Thanks!

EDIT : Also tried this version, but got the same error :

```
int estImage(struct dirent *fichier)
{

    char nomFichier[256]; // Variable qui contiendra le nom du fichier
    strncpy (nomFichier, fichier->d_name, 255);
    char *dot = strrchr(nomFichier, '.');

    int retour=0;

    if( (!strcmp(dot,".jpg")) || (!strcmp(dot,".png")) || (!strcmp(dot,".jpeg")) || (!strcmp(dot,".bmp")) ) 
        retour = 1;

    return retour;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129508/discussion-on-question-by-alan-segmentation-fault-error-while-trying-to-get-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
int estImage(struct dirent *fichier)
{
    char nomFichier[256];
    strncpy (nomFichier, fichier->d_name, 255);

    char *dot = strrchr(nomFichier, '.');

    if (dot == NULL)
       return 0;  // no extension => it's not an image

    char * listeExtensionImage[] = {".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp" };
    int len = sizeof(listeExtensionImage)/sizeof(listeExtensionImage[0]);

    printf(dot); //Just to test

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(listeExtensionImage[i], dot) == 0)
            return 1;   // image extension found
    }

    return 0;   // no image extension found
}
```

Comment: It's hard to diff manually. It may have been discussed in the 30 comments, but if there is an accepted answer it should stand on its own. Why don't you give an explanation and highlight the difference?

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to Marian, we caught the error. The function estImage() is called in a for-loop, that's supposed to list all the files in a directory. That loop probably caught an invisible file, or something with an empty name, and the dot variable was NULL. So, the working code is :

```
int estImage(struct dirent *fichier)
{

    char nomFichier[256]; // Variable qui contiendra le nom du fichier
    strncpy (nomFichier, fichier->d_name, 255);

    char *dot = strrchr(nomFichier, '.');

    int retour=0;


    if( dot!=NULL && ((!strcmp(dot,".jpg")) || (!strcmp(dot,".png")) || (!strcmp(dot,".jpeg")) || (!strcmp(dot,".bmp"))) ) //Si le fichier est une image
        retour = 1; // On retourne 1

    return retour;


}
```

Thanks a lot to everyone that helped me!

Comment: But this function is uggly. The original version with `char * listeExtensionImage[] = {".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp" };` is far more elegant. And no, there is no mystery. Simply if you have a file without extension (which is common) `strchr(xxx, '.');` returns `NULL`.